# Moving Files to Different Folders Based on the Part of Their File Name

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a script that will move PDF files to a different folder according to a part of the file name. Here are a few sample file names:

```
Additional documents_Joe Root.pdf
Relevant past items_Joe Root.pdf
Important file list_Joe Root.pdf
Highly classified docs_David Williams.pdf
searched useful items_David Williams.pdf
```

I need the files with `_Joe Root` to be moved to folder called `"Joe Root"`
and files with `"_David Williams"` to be moved to a folder call `"David Williams"`.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:javascript] and what have you tried so far?

Comment: were not a coding service, 
There is no question here,

Comment: Not sure if it's not related to javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, it's important to include all the code necessary to understand the problem, and to include it here in the question and not just via a link to some off-site resource. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do the folders `Joe Root` already exist or do they have to be created? A for and a staged For /f to parse the name should do. There are lots of examples here on [SO], you should do a bit more research and present your code in the [edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45445478/edit) when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

Don't test this on your only copy of those files. Make a copy of the root folder you are working with. Then test this code on the copy.

```
# Create the folders. 
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | Select-Object -Unique | % { New-Item -ItemType directory $_ } | Out-Null

# Move the files. 
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination ".\$($Matches[1])\$_" } | Out-Null
```

### Demo

If you want to see how this works then follow these steps.

1. Create an empty folder.
2. Open Powershell.
3. Change directory to the empty folder.
4. Run the code below to create dummy files:

   ```
   $examples = @(
       "Additional documents_Joe Root.pdf",
       "Relevant past items_Joe Root.pdf",
       "Important file list_Joe Root.pdf",
       "Highly classified docs_David Williams.pdf",
       "searched useful items_David Williams.pdf"
   )

   $examples | % { New-Item -ItemType file $_ } | Out-Null
   ```
5. Run the first script on this demo folder.

Notice there are no subfolders to begin with. And work has not started (no files have been moved into subfolders.) All the PDF files are in one folder. And the script does the work of creating subfolders and moving files.

## Explanation

First, let me correct the original code. I used a subexpression operator, $(), where it was not needed.

```
$($_.BaseName)
```

becomes

```
$_.BaseName
```

Here are the updated commands:

```
# Create the folders. 
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | Select-Object -Unique | % { New-Item -ItemType directory $_ } | Out-Null

# Move the files. 
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination ".\$($Matches[1])\$_" } | Out-Null
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem?view=powershell-5.1) lists the files and folders in the folder where the script is launched.

-Filter is a parameter of Get-ChildItem. It lets me limit what files and folders are returned.

I prefer

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf
```

because it only ever grabs PDF files.

Whereas

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf
```

grabs all files in the folder and then only shows you PDF files.

The difference is in how many files are touched in the process. Using -Filter is more efficient because the provider applies it when retrieving the objects rather than retrieving all objects and then filtering them. The performance difference can be significant when there are many files in the folder or when you are referencing remote computers.

Since I am dealing with files and folders, -Filter will invoke the [FileSystem provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/filesystem-provider?view=powershell-6). The FileSystem provider recognizes [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) wildcards. * is a wildcard character meaning match any number of any characters. So that corresponds to the part of the file name from before the file extension. The .pdf corresponds to the file extension. For this script, I'm only interested in PDF files.

```
a test file.pdf
          *.pdf
```

[| (pipe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Pipe) glues the [cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648597(v=vs.85).aspx) together. PowerShell benefits from two main features. One, PowerShell is object oriented. Two, PowerShell has an object pipeline. This means that you can do meaningful things by connecting the output of one cmdlet to the input of another.

```
    cmdlet      cmdlet 
      v         v     
Get-ChildItem | % {  }
              ^       
              pipe
```

So, in the first part of the command, Get-ChildItem is generating file objects ([System.IO.FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)). And those are being piped to other cmdlets in the pipeline: ex. the output from Get-ChildItem is the input for %.

The pipeline is all the cmdlets connected by pipes.

Moving on, % is an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1) for [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-5.1). ForEach-Object lets you insert arbitrary code into the pipeline. This way you can customize the work your pipeline does without having to rely solely on cmdlets.

The first question you will have about ForEach-Object is how to specify the current object in the pipeline. That is accomplished with $*. [$](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html)* is an automatic variable that corresponds to the current object in the pipeline. An automatic variable is a variable that PowerShell provides automatically in certain contexts (like inside a pipeline). Every time you see $_, I am referring the the current object in the pipeline.

Get-ChildItem will output System.IO.FileInfo objects for files it encounters on the file system. FileInfo objects have a ScriptProperty called BaseName. This property stores the file name from before the file extension.

[ScriptProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psmembertypes(v=vs.85).aspx) are properties calculated for PowerShell objects. You can view what ScriptProperties are available by [piping objects to Get-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx). You might also find [this page](https://ss64.com/ps/get-member.html) helpful.

So if

```
$a = Get-Item 'a test file.pdf'
```

then

```
$a.BaseName
```

produces 'a test file' (without the quotes). Here, $a is my FileInfo object.

And the dot in my command

```
$a.BaseName
  ^
```

is the [property dereference operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators). It let's PowerShell know I'm looking for the BaseName property of the FileInfo object stored in $a.

So, you should be able to understand this command so far.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName }
```

It reads take the PDF files in the current folder and for each file, give me the file name from before the file extension.

Next in the pipeline is the [-match operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-5.1#matching-operators). It is a comparison operator. It is comparing the BaseName of each file to my regular expression which I will explain later. One subtlety here is that my input is a scalar value (a single string).

Every time

```
$_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$"
```

is evaluated, it is only operating on the current value of BaseName which is a single string.

Strings represent text in PowerShell.

-match changes its behavior depending on whether its input is scalar or a collection. For scalar input, -match populates the $Matches automatic variable which is important.

A [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a search pattern. I tell the computer when I want to see a letter, a number, or a symbol in a string. I say how many times that character can be matched. I can also apply other rules. And the computer gives me the matches.

The essence of regular expressions is the abstract way of representing letters and numbers so that the computer can understand what you are looking for.

My regular expression is

```
"_([a-zA-Z ]+)$"
```

- a-z means match any lowercase alphabet character like a, b, c; etc.
- A-Z means match any uppercase alphabet character.
- [] means build a character class. In other words, match any one of the characters inside the square brackets [a-zA-Z ]. Also notice that I include a space inside my character class.
- `+` means match one or more characters inside the class. So I won't just match 'D', I'll match 'David Williams'.
- The parentheses mean save this part of the match as a separate variable. In other words, I want 'David Williams' (no underscore).
- _ is a literal underscore. It ensures that any match from inside the parentheses will occur after the underscore.
- $ means the end of the string for regular expressions. I am looking for a match between _ and the end of the string. So _ and $ are the ends of my regular expression. Remember that we're only looking at BaseName here. So, .pdf is not included in the string.
- The regular expression is saved as a string. So it appears in double quotes.

Here is the process of forming a regular expression.

```
Highly classified docs_David Williams
Step 1                _              $  Mark the ends of the match. 
Step 2                _(            )$  Save the name as a backreference. 
Step 3                _([a-z]       )$  Begin a character class that will match one lowercase letter. 
Step 4                _([a-zA-Z])$      Match uppercase letters. Remove extra spaces. 
Step 5                _([a-zA-Z ])$     Match the space between the first and last name. 
Step 6                _([a-zA-Z ]+)$    Add + to match one or more characters from the character class.
```

There is an [old article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) for VBScript that introduced me to regular expressions. You might find it helpful. [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is also a good reference.

I have not explained the significance of the [$Matches automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Comparison_Operators?view=powershell-5.1#matching-operators). Remember that for scalar input, -match populates the $Matches automatic variable. So, the match inside the parentheses will get saved as a backreference (regular expression variable). And I can refer to it later. In this particular case, `$Matches[1]` will refer to the person's name such as 'David Williams'.

Now you should be able to understand this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" }
```

It says take the PDF files in the current folder and for each file, save the person's name to `$Matches[1]` and output $true.

Now the reason the code outputs $true is because of the way -match works. When the input is scalar, -match returns a Boolean value and sets the value of the $Matches automatic variable to the matched components of the argument. Since we don't need the Boolean, we can discard it. Out-Null discards any output it receives.

```
$_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null;
```

Here, Out-Null is not part of the main pipeline. It falls within the script block of the first ForEach-Object.

```
| % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | 
^                           The main pipeline.                      ^

| % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | 
    ^                       %'s script block.                     ^  

| % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | 
                       A local pipeline.  ^                          

| % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | 
A semicolon which separates statements on the same  ^  line.
```

Moving on, the `$Matches[1]` within the ForEach-Object script block means to output the person's name as a string.

Now you should be able to understand this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] }
```

It outputs the name associated with each file as a string.

I intend to create folders. And I will do that by piping the output to a cmdlet that makes a folder for each name it receives.

The problem is that if a person is associated with more than one file then the command will output that person's name multiple times. The cmdlet creating folders will try to create the same folder multiple times. I want one string for each unique person.

So, I pipe the output to Select-Object with the -Unique parameter. That will output one copy of each name it receives.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | Select-Object -Unique
```

The next step is to create the folders. I use New-Item and specify -ItemType directory. Here directory means folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | Select-Object -Unique | % { New-Item -ItemType directory $_ }
```

The final step is to discard the output from New-Item by using Out-Null. And that gives the complete command to create folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] } | Select-Object -Unique | % { New-Item -ItemType directory $_ } | Out-Null
```

Moving the files is similar up to this point:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; }
```

Within that ForEach-Object script block, I match the name, as before, but now I move files using the match.

Move the file

```
-Path $_
```

to the folder

```
-Destination ".\$($Matches[1])\$_"
```

- .\ is the local folder: where the script is working.
- Here I actually need the subexpression operator, $(), to bring the text of `$Matches[1]` into the string.
- And \ separates folders like it would in any path.

The subexpression operator, $(), evaluates any PowerShell expression and inserts the result in the string.

So,

```
> "$($Matches[1])"  # Produces
David Williams
```

and

```
> "$Matches[1]"
System.Collections.Hashtable[1]
```

Without the subexpression operator, the command gives `System.Collections.Hashtable[1]` instead of a folder name.

Here is the complete command to move files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | % { $_.BaseName -match "_([a-zA-Z ]+)$" | Out-Null; Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination ".\$($Matches[1])\$_" } | Out-Null
```

As before, I discard the output from the moves with Out-Null.

Comment: Hi Mike, it worked perfectly and I am over the moon. Thank you so much. I wonder if you can explain a bit about your script and how it works. Anyways, I am so trilled and again thank you so much for your help. Take care!

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't get a chance to review it until now. I am about to review it now.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$tartpath="c:\temp"

Get-ChildItem $tartpath -file -filter "*.pdf" | where name -like '*_*' |  %{
    $newdir="{0}\{1}" -f $tartpath, ($_.basename -split '_')[-1]
    new-Item $newdir -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Move-Item $_.FullName $newdir
}
```