# Create directories and subdirectories in Powershell to move files

Tags: powershell, directory

I am trying to create directories and subdirectories based on the names of existing files. After that I want to move those files into the according directories. I have already come pretty far, also with the help of
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837516/powershell-command-script-to-move-files-to-subdirectories-based-on-date-in-th) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445478/moving-files-to-different-folders-based-on-the-part-of-their-file-name), but I am failing at some point.

| Existing Test Files *Actually about 5000 files* | Folder structure *This is how it should look like afterwards* |
| --- | --- |
| MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt | MM\MM0245\625\G03\MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt |
| MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt | MM\MM0245\830\G04\MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt |
| VY0245AK_G03.txt | VY\VY0245\VY0245AK_G03.txt |
| VY0245AK_G03_701.txt | VY\VY0245\G03\VY0245AK_G03_701.txt |
| VY0245AK625_G03.txt | VY\VY0245\625\VY0245AK625_G03.txt |
| VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt | VY\VY0245\625\G03\VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt |
| VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt | VY\VY0345\625\G03\VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt |

Code for creating those files is at the end of this post.

As you can see, the files do match some kind of pattern, but not consistently. I use multiple copies of my code with different 'parameters' to sort each type of filepattern, but there gotta be a more streamline way.

**Existing code**

```
$dataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Test"
#$newDataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\"
Get-ChildItem $dataPath -Filter *.txt | % {
    $g1 = $_.BaseName.Substring(0, 2)
    $g2 = $_.BaseName.Substring(0, 6)
    $g3 = $_.BaseName.Substring(8, 3)
    $g4 = $_.BaseName.Substring(12, 3)

    $path = "$DataPath\$g1\$g2\$g3\$g4"
    if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
    }

    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $path
}
```

This code also creates directories in the 3rd `$g3` layer for files in "the shorter format", e.g. XX0000AK_G00.txt. This file should however not be moved further than layer `$g2`. Of course the code above is not capable of doing this, so I tried it with regex below.

This is an alternative idea (not worked out furhter than creating directories), but I failed to continue after
`Select-Object -Unique`. I am failing to use `$Matches[1]` in `New-Item`, because I can only `Select-Object -unique` the variable `$_`, not `$Matches[1]` or even the subdirectory `"$($Matches[1])$($Matches[2])"`. The following code is my attempt.

```
cd $PSScriptRoot\Test

# Create Folder Layer 1 
Get-ChildItem  |
    % {
        $_.BaseName -match "^(\w{2})(\d{4})AN(\d{3})?_(G\d{2})(_\d{3})?$" | Out-Null
        $Matches[1]
        "$($Matches[1])$($Matches[2])"
        } |
    Select-Object -Unique |
    % {
        New-Item -ItemType directory $_ 
        } | Out-Null
```

I am fairly new to powershell, please don't be too harsh :) I also don't have a programming background, so please excuse the use of incorrect wording.

```
new-item $dataPath\MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt -ItemType File   
new-item $dataPath\VY0245AK_G03.txt -ItemType File   
new-item $dataPath\VY0245AK_G03_701.txt -ItemType File   
new-item $dataPath\VY0245AK625_G03.txt -ItemType File   
new-item $dataPath\VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt -ItemType File  
new-item $dataPath\VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt -ItemType File
```

Answer (score 0):

i am truly bad at complex regex patterns [*blush*], so this is done with simple string ops, mostly.

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in some files
  when you have tested this and it works as needed on all your test files, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with a `Get-ChildItem` call.
- iterates thru the collection
- splits the BaseName on `ak` & saves it for later use
- checks for a the two short file layouts
- checks for 1 `_` versus 2
- builds the `$Dir` string for each of those 2 filename layouts
- builds the long file name `$Dir`
- uses the previous `$Dir` stuff to build the `$FullDest` for each file
- shows the various stages for each file

that last section would be replaced with your `mkdir` & `Move-Item` commands.

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in files
#    when ready to use the real things, use $Get-ChildItem
$InStuff = @'
MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt
MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt
VY0245AK_G03.txt
VY0245AK_G03_701.txt
VY0245AK625_G03.txt
VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt
VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$_
        }
#endregion >>> fake reading in files

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $BNSplit_1 = $IS_Item.BaseName -split 'ak'

    if ($BNSplit_1[-1].StartsWith('_'))
        {
        if (($BNSplit_1[-1] -replace '[^_]').Length -eq 1)
            {
            $Dir = '{0}\{1}' -f $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 2),
                    $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 6)
            }
            else
            {
            $Dir = '{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 2),
                $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 6),
                $IS_Item.BaseName.Split('_')[1]
            }
        }
        else
        {
        $Dir = '{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}' -f $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 2),
            $IS_Item.BaseName.Substring(0, 6),
            $BNSplit_1[-1].Split('_')[0],
            $BNSplit_1[-1].Split('_')[1]

        }

    $FullDest = Join-Path -Path $Dir -ChildPath $IS_Item

    #region >>> show what was done with each file        
    #    replace this block with your MkDir & Move-Item commands
    $IS_Item.Name
    $Dir
    $FullDest
    'depth = {0}' -f ($FullDest.Split('\').Count - 1)
    '=' * 20
    #endregion >>> show what was done with each file        
    }
```

the output ...

```
MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt
MM\MM0245\625\G03
MM\MM0245\625\G03\MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt
depth = 4
====================
MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt
MM\MM0245\830\G04
MM\MM0245\830\G04\MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt
depth = 4
====================
VY0245AK_G03.txt
VY\VY0245
VY\VY0245\VY0245AK_G03.txt
depth = 2
====================
VY0245AK_G03_701.txt
VY\VY0245\G03
VY\VY0245\G03\VY0245AK_G03_701.txt
depth = 3
====================
VY0245AK625_G03.txt
VY\VY0245\625\G03
VY\VY0245\625\G03\VY0245AK625_G03.txt
depth = 4
====================
VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt
VY\VY0245\625\G03
VY\VY0245\625\G03\VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt
depth = 4
====================
VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt
VY\VY0345\625\G03
VY\VY0345\625\G03\VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt
depth = 4
====================
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first split each file BaseName on the underscore. Then use a regex to split the first part into several array elements, combine that with a possible second part of the split in order to create the destination folder path for the files.

```
$DataPath = "$PSScriptRoot\Test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $DataPath -Filter '*_*.txt' -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $parts = $file.BaseName -split '_'
    # regex your way to split the first part into path elements (remove empty items)
    $folders = [regex]::Match($parts[0], '(?i)^(.{2})(\d{4})[A-Z]{2}(\d{3})?').Groups[1..3].Value | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S'}
    # the second part is a merge with the first part
    $folders[1] = $folders[0] + $folders[1]
    # if there was a third part after the split on the underscore, add $part[1] (i.e. 'Gxx') to the folders array
    if ($parts.Count -gt 2) { $folders += $parts[1] }

    # join the array elements with a backslash (i.e. [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)
    # and join all tat to the $DataPath to create the full destination for the file
    $target = Join-Path -Path $DataPath -ChildPath ($folders -join '\')

    # create the folder if that does not yet exist
    $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory -Force
    # move the file to that (new) directory
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $target -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>The `-WhatIf` switch makes the code not move anything to the new destination, it will only **display** where the file would go to. Once you are happy with that information, remove `-WhatIf` and run the code again</sup>

After moving your filestructure will look like this:

```
D:\TEST
+---MM
|   \---MM0245
|       +---625
|       |   \---G03
|       |           MM0245AK625_G03_701.txt
|       |           
|       \---830
|           \---G04
|                   MM0245AK830_G04_701.txt
|                   
\---VY
    +---VY0245
    |   |   VY0245AK_G03.txt
    |   |   
    |   +---625
    |   |   |   VY0245AK625_G03.txt
    |   |   |   
    |   |   \---G03
    |   |           VY0245AK625_G03_701.txt
    |   |           
    |   \---G03
    |           VY0245AK_G03_701.txt
    |           
    \---VY0345
        \---625
            \---G03
                    VY0345AK625_G03_701.txt
```